# Redis — best way to store a large map (dictionary)

Tags: redis

What I need to do is to store a one-to-one mapping. The dataset consists of a large number of key-value pairs of the same kind (10M+). For example, one could use a single instance of HashMap object in Java for storing such data.

The first way to do this is to store lots of key-value pairs, like this:

```
SET map:key1 value1
...
SET map:key900000 value900000
GET map:key1
```

The second option is to use a single "Hash":

```
HSET map key1 value
...
HSET map key900000 value900000
HGET map key1
```

Redis Hashes have some convenient commands (`HMSET`, `HMGET`, `HGETALL`, etc.), and they don't pollute the keyspace, so this looks like a better option. However, are there any performance or memory considerations when using this approach?

Comment: This is actually a recommended use pattern to save some RAM with Redis - http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization#using-hashes-to-abstract-a-very-memory-efficient-plain-key-value-store-on-top-of-redis

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, as [Itamar Haber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3160475/itamar-haber) says, you should look at this [redis memory optimization guide](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization#using-hashes-to-abstract-a-very-memory-efficient-plain-key-value-store-on-top-of-redis).  But you should also keep in mind a few more things:

1. Prefer HSET to KEYS. Redis consumes a lot of memory just on key space management. In simple (and rough) terms, 1 HSET with 1,000,000 keys consumes up to 10x less memory than 1,000,000 keys with one value each.
2. Keep HSET size less then `hash-max-zipmap-entries` and valid `hash-max-zipmap-value` if memory is the main target. Be sure to understand what `hash-max-zipmap-entries` and `hash-max-zipmap-value` mean. Also, take some time to read about ziplist.
3. You actually do not want to handle `hash-max-zipmap-entries` with 10M+ keys; instead, you should break one HSET into multiple slots. For example, you set `hash-max-zipmap-entries` as 10,000. So to store 10M+ keys you need 1000+ HSET keys with 10,000 each. As a rough rule of thumb: crc32(key) % maxHsets.
4. Read about [strings in redis](http://redis.io/topics/internals-sds) and use a KEY name (in HSET) length based on real memory management for this structure. In simple terms, keeping key length under 7 bytes, you spend 16 bytes per key, but an 8-byte key spends 48 bytes each. Why? Read about [simple dynamic strings](https://github.com/antirez/sds).

It may be useful to read about:

- [Redis Memory Optimization](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools/wiki/Redis-Memory-Optimization) (from sripathikrishnan)
- [Comments about internal ziplist structure](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/ziplist.c).
- [Storing hundreds of millions of simple key-value pairs in Redis (Instagram)](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value)

Comment: Check out the graphs on https://www.peterbe.com/plog/understanding-redis-hash-max-ziplist-entries where the total database memory footprint is compared to different ways of storing things.

Comment: #3 option is very good. bucketing the key will give you advantage of the zipmap and also greatly reduce the number of main key in redis. and in the meanwhile put and get are both still O(1) ops.